# closed form of a summation with binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The following summation came up while I was exploring some multivariate generalizations of the [asymmetric Laplace distribution](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920500199018) sometimes used in Bayesian quantile regression.
$n$ is a positive integer, and $\lambda$ is a positive real.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(n - k)^{n - k}}{\lambda^k (n + \lambda k)^{n - k}}
$$

Does this reduce to a closed form? It looks like some kind of [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) style identity could apply, but I haven't been able to figure anything out. I've tried looking at $\lambda=1$ as a special case in the hopes it would be simpler, but no luck.